# Remotely manipulate program which interfaces with laboratory instruments

Tags: apache, unix, web, windows-xp

I have written an application in VB which reads and displays data from instruments
and change their settings. These instruments are in my lab, but and I want to access them remotely from my room or anywhere outside my campus LAN through a web server. After searching the net I realised the best thing to do would be to use an Apache server.

1. Should my VB application run within the apache server? Apparently there is something called an application server.
2. As an alternative approach, should I write an application within the server that takes data from the code I have written and then uses or modifies it?

Or is there any other approach to the problem I am failing to see?